# How to match array values which is inside v-for loop in Vuejs?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my code, I have 3 arrays called, **boxes, paints, matchingdata**. By using those arrays, i want to perfome the functionality.

After the checkbox is clicked, At present i am showing some information related to **paints array**

So i need to set the condition here like.

if checkox is clicked, **i only need to show the paint array two id's called (100, 101)**

Comment: take a look here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61346109/error-in-vuex-computed-property-was-assigned-to-but-it-has-no-setter

Answer (score 0):

You must return something from the computed property status

Comment: In my case, I have already returned status in the template.

      template: `<div  :class="{ green: status = 'ok',   red: status === 'notok',  pink: status === 'medium', }">{{status}}</div>`,

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the template inside script and add it inside the template inside the other template where you have the rest of html code and it should work well.